# Running pip install inside the docker container works for every python package except for dependency-injector

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dependency-injection, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following in the docker file:

```
    FROM python:3.7.5-alpine3.10 as base

    FROM base as builder
    RUN mkdir /install
    WORKDIR /install
    COPY dependencies.txt /dependencies.txt
    RUN pip install --install-option="--prefix=/install" -r /dependencies.txt
```

dependencies.txt is as follows:

```
    multitasking
    dependency-injector
```

If dependency-injector is removed, it installs all the packages but with the presenceof dependency-injector, I get the below error when the docker image builds, I get the below error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r /requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
    (base) cosmos@ubuntu:~/git/newest/bigbang/bb-collector/partial_profiler$ sudo ./build_container.sh 
    Building common and partial_profiler container
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  625.2kB
    Step 1/14 : FROM python:3.7.5-alpine3.10 as base
     ---> 8922d588eec6
    Step 2/14 : FROM base as builder
     ---> 8922d588eec6
    Step 3/14 : RUN mkdir /install
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 3f62ef86c42b
    Step 4/14 : WORKDIR /install
     ---> Using cache
     ---> acc30ad7c3e7
    Step 5/14 : COPY dependencies.txt /dependencies.txt
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 9722c2a49839
    Step 6/14 : RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r /dependencies.txt
     ---> Running in 9f44aa710486
    Collecting redis
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/05/1fc7feedc19c123e7a95cfc9e7892eb6cdd2e5df4e9e8af6384349c1cc3d/redis-3.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
    Collecting kafka-python
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/34/12f219f7f9e68e79a54874d26fbe974db1ab4efac4e6dae665b421df48f9/kafka_python-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (232kB)
    Collecting multitasking
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/e7/e9f1661c28f7b87abfa08cb0e8f51dad2240a9f4f741f02ea839835e6d18/multitasking-0.0.9.tar.gz
    Collecting dependency-injector
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/9a/344c06f03503046260116e4f2a9887d8f720a3914c760c81b78d47a9f926/dependency-injector-3.15.6.tar.gz (334kB)
    Collecting six<=1.14.0,>=1.7.0
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/eb/1f97cb97bfc2390a276969c6fae16075da282f5058082d4cb10c6c5c1dba/six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Building wheels for collected packages: multitasking, dependency-injector
      Building wheel for multitasking (setup.py): started
      Building wheel for multitasking (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Created wheel for multitasking: filename=multitasking-0.0.9-cp37-none-any.whl size=8368 sha256=cc3d1d0a59d461567e563485f6306110069122913b1d5f2ea6b1f2cb7c9c7a45
      Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/37/fa/73/d492849e319038eb4d986f5152e4b19ffb1bc0639da84d2677
      Building wheel for dependency-injector (setup.py): started
      Building wheel for dependency-injector (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kkjw147/dependency-injector/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kkjw147/dependency-injector/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-zjrhhvrm --python-tag cp37
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2kkjw147/dependency-injector/
      Complete output (18 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/dependency_injector
      copying src/dependency_injector/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/dependency_injector
      copying src/dependency_injector/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/dependency_injector
      copying src/dependency_injector/containers.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/dependency_injector
      copying src/dependency_injector/providers.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/dependency_injector
      running build_ext
      building 'dependency_injector.containers' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/dependency_injector
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c src/dependency_injector/containers.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/dependency_injector/containers.o -O2
      unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for dependency-injector
```

This is the error I get. But if I try installing with pip install dependency-injector outside docker i.e in my Ubuntu box, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the gcc and some other packages to build this package. add the below lines to your docker file and it will solve the issue

```
RUN apk update && apk add g++
```

complete example

```
 FROM python:3.7.5-alpine3.10 as base
 RUN apk update && apk add g++

 FROM base as builder
 RUN mkdir /install
 WORKDIR /install
 COPY dependencies.txt /dependencies.txt
 RUN pip install --install-option="--prefix=/install" -r /dependencies.txt
```

Comment: Thanks  @Al-waleed  for giving me the hint of gcc. The above did not work for me but, the following worked:RUN apk update && \
    apk add g++

Comment: I updated the solutions, Just in case others need it